# IDO mode: How to go to beginning of line in minibuffer?

Tags: ido, ido-find-file

When using IDO mode when I start searching for files it always begins in the working directory of my current file.

Usually I like this, however, if I want to search in a significantly different directory I like to press `C-a` to go to the beginning of the minibuffer.  However, with IDO that does not work and I stay in my current directory.

Is there a way to change this and go to the beginning?

I suppose I could just type `/` but...old habits die hard.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have ido-mode enabled, I recommend entering `C-e` at the minibuffer prompt which maps to `ido-edit-input` (instead of taking you to the end of the line).  Then you will have `C-a`, `C-k`, and the rest of the original emacs bindings restored.